# Spring form:select issue

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I wrote the simple code in the jsp using form:select

```
<form:select id="a" path="validPath">
<form:option value="x"/>
<form:option value="y"/>
</form:select>
```

Here Its showing whole box and showing these 2 items. Its not looking like a drop down box. Its showing all options in a single huge box. To make more clear its showing all option even without selecting

Something like x y ...

I am not sure how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work. You can refer this link for more information :
[Spring MVC Dropdown Box Example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/)
Make sure you have added its library
`<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>`

Comment: Its working fine but the problem is, it's showing all the menu options at a time. What I meant is I can view X and Y options even without selecting.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I am unable to share the screenshot of it. To make it more clear Let's say I have 3 items in the select box( A B C). Normally when we click on select box it shows 3 items. Right ?.  But in my case it's showing all the 3 options without selecting through the cursor like a a text box with 3 options.